# Troubleshooting expensive potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, troubleshooting

Tl;dr tested pot and it doesn't show any variation across center pin. Is it reasonable to conclude it is the broken part?

Hey everybody,
so recently a coworker and I were reassembling an expensive piece of lab equipment that involves a pot for speed control of a stepper motor. Everything was working pretty well, but while replacing the button that sits over the pot, someone decided that brute force was the way to attach it and hit the button. The stepper no longer turns. Looking at the board nothing appears different, but I grabbed a multimeter and stuck it on the pot where the center pin showed no variation no matter how it was turned. Is it reasonable to conclude that just the pot broke? What else would a more experienced trouble shooter check before ordering a replacement that costs $80-$120?
[image: pot in question]

Comment: Are you sure that thing in your picture is a potentiometer?

Comment: Well it sure looks like on and says 12k on the side? What's the alternative in that case? Variable cap?

Comment: Even in circuit, when the pot is at the extreme ends of it settings, there should be low resistance from the center to the terminal that it is turned towards.  If this resistance does not change as the pot is turned, then the wiper is probably not in contact with the main resistor.  You can of course desolder it and check it again before ordering a new one.

Comment: Contact spray? Turn it back and forth many times over to wear away any oxide?

Comment: What does the identifier label on the board say? It is covered by the thread in your photo

Comment: Double checked and I meant to say 10K before. It's showing the same value on the center pin no matter how it's turned so I believe you are correct. Is there anything else you would check before desoldering a board that would cost upwards of $3000 to replace if it gets damaged?

Comment: identifier says RU1. so potentiometer seems highly likely.

Comment: I recommend what @crj11 wrote - desolder it from the board and check it with an ohmmeter.  Maybe while looking at the solder joints you'll see one that's cracked and the problem is not with the pot itself.

Comment: Alright. Thanks everyone. I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect another 10K pot in parallel if you want to test it. Leave the existing one set around the middle and see if the functionality comes back. Take care nothing shorts or you may create much worse problems.

Your main concern when you get the replacement pot is to avoid damaging the board (especially the plated through holes). If you don't have really good rework tools (eg.)

[image]

one good approach is to **cut the existing pot apart** and remove one lead at a time, cleaning the holes up with good solder wick.

That method precludes the desolder and test method you are thinking of following.

---

Of course even if the board is so mutilated, it's generally possible to hack a replacement on there with fly wires, epoxy and such like, but better avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Consensus from comments is to desolder potentiometer from board and check with an ohmmeter. All credit to those who left comments especially @crj11.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 terminals (not counting the bracket mounting holes) and only rotates through about 270 degrees, it is a pot. (If there are more and if it rotates through 360 it is likely a rotary encoder.) But it looks like a 1980's pot made by a company called Preh. You see these commonly in British audio pro mixing desks of that time.

Getting it out will be a pain if the PCB holes are tight, which is likely. But it is possible with patience. If you can find some way to heat all the pins simultaneously that would help but that probably isn't possible because it is physically too big. But - if you damage a track on one or two of the mounting pins, it is no big deal (they have no electrical function) and even if you damage the tracks going to the pot itself you can repair with wire. It happens sometimes, inevitably, and it's not the end of the world.

(The trick for removal is to go at each pin and use a combination of solder sucker and wick to try to get all solder out, then gently move the pin before it cools to stop the remaining solder forming a bond. You can tell if this works by seeing whether the pin feels free when cold. If there is only a small amount of solder you can often break the bond by tweaking the pin with fine pliers. When all or nearly all are free, you can usually remove the pot. Patience and accuracy will get you much further than a fancy rework station.)

When you get it out, just test it with a meter. You are interested in end to end resistance and also the law, which you find by measuring end to wiper with the pot centred. However, from what you say, it is likely that your colleague open circuited the wiper (or made it intermittent) by hitting it. I have seen this in gear that has been dropped on the front panel.

A replacement should not be more than 10$ but because it is old and not obtainable they are likely working you over a bit. But if you can work out the value you can use any pot of the right value that you can mount successfully on the panel. Just use wire to connect to the board. If the law is wrong, it is often possible to slug it acceptably with a resistor from wiper to wrong end. How well this will work depends very much on specifics of the circuit.

(Looking at the circuit I am guessing that value is not that critical - I'd hazard a guess that it is just being used to generate a DC voltage which is getting sampled by that DAC and read by the micro. This is a typical 80s/early 90s approach. If that is the case any old 10k pot may well do the job.)

Answer (score 0):

While removing the pot and testing it is the obvious way to go, you should be aware that first you need to understand the circuit it's in. There are two ways to use a potentiometer: as a potentiometer (variable resistive divider) and as a variable resistor.

Potentiometer: something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fctp3R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Variable resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRvpWz.png)</sup>

Why do you need to know which is which? Because if the pot is being used as a variable resistor, and you check between the wiper and the lower terminal, it will always read zero ohms not matter how the pot is turned.

Since the pot is next to a DAC08, which is a current-output DAC, it's possible that the DAC output is driving the pot as a variable resistor in order to get a variable voltage which varies with shaft position. Frankly, this sounds unlikely, but you never know what sort of weird circuit designs you might encounter.

With all of that said, I'd go with removing the pot and testing it.